# drop down menu bootstrap code

Tags: html, jquery-ui, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on the twitter bootstrap website
using this example to develop my site
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html
but the problem is when i reduce my browser size i see the menu icon but when i click it i dont see the drop down menu
how to fix it 
providing my code below

http://jsfiddle.net/LCJ2V/

```
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is that, based on the code in your jsfiddle, you are not properly loading external resources.

For the boostrap .js files, try this:

```
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
```

Another issue is that jsfiddle's `.window_label` element is covering the top right corner of the navbar. One way to get rid of it, using Google Chrome, is to use the html inspector
and delete the `.window_label` node for an unencumbered view of the navbar button.

Comment: thanks for your email i updated in the js but its not working http://jsfiddle.net/LCJ2V/3/

Comment: @user1943618 - you added the new src files, but you also left in the bad src links. See line 1433 of you /3 file. Here's an updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/LCJ2V/4/